# how to publish an Eigen::Vector3f& in ROS

Tags: ros, pcl, eigen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im using a PCL code and the information I need is in a Eigen::Vector3f&, how to i publish this information in ROS. What is the type of the publisher?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93211/how-to-publish-an-eigen::vector3f&-in-ros/) by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2013-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped

```
$ rosmsg show geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped 
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
geometry_msgs/Vector3 vector
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
```

You can browse messages with

```
rosmsg list
```

Publishing this as a topic is good described in the publisher and subscriber tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-29**:
@BennyRe  how do i publish such a topic, i can manage to make it work.  i have a n.advertise<std_msgs::Float32>  how do i change it to the vector? thanks

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-29**:
@BennyRe thanks also is there any standard array message? thanks

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-10-29**:
Do you mean an array of Vector3s?

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-29**:
@BennyRe no just a 2x1 array of floats

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-10-29**:
A quick look at rosmsg list shows you the message std_msgs/Float32MultiArray